# Remove words after a particular word in a long string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

As i want to extract a portion from a string, i use the following code

```
c_name = Str.Substring(Str.IndexOf("Name ") + 5)
```

But it **eliminate the portion which i want**. is their any possibility t select words up to certain word/Remove words after a particular word in a long string

Comment: can you show an example of what you expect and what you receive?

Comment: let the string be **can you show an example of what you expect and what you receive**  i want to extract ** you expect **

Comment: @user3844123, this explains nothing. Show desired inputs, outputs and - most important - rule what do you want to extract. If someone puts so little effort in explaining its problem, the same effort will be applied while answering. PS. In english write "I", not "i".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
c_name = Str.Substring(Str.IndexOf("Name ") + 5)
```

You can't add + 5 inside the indexOf() as it would probably be interpreted as indexOf('Name 5'), but instead you should be able to do indexOf('Name ') + 5.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
c_name = Str.Substring(Str.IndexOf("Name ") + 5)
```

instead of

```
c_name = Str.Substring(Str.IndexOf("Name " + 5))
```

**Updated:** as per your question/clarified in comment:

```
c_name = Str.Substring(0, Str.IndexOf("Name ")
```

Comment: But it is the actual problem i am facing it will give only the string after"Name",i want the up to name